# Xamarinforms DatePicker how to change textbox's fontsize

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have  an app  created with : xamarinforms -prism - materialDesign
I wold like to change the default the inner textbox's fontsize of the DatePicker, TimePicker controls, because it is to big, I 'd like a smaller text, my code is:

```
<DatePicker Date="{Binding mydate,Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="10"/>
```

No matter  the size I set to FontSize, it doesn't work at all, the same happens with TimePicker,

any help will be great,
thanks in advance

Comment: yes it finally works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone  goes through this,  finally works just using this

```
<DatePicker Date="{Binding mydate,Mode=TwoWay}" 
FontSize="Body" TextColor="{DynamicResource Key=QuaternaryColor}"/>
```

the same for the timePicker

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CustomRender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction) to achieve this:

For Android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker), typeof(AndroidDatePickerRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace
{
  class AndroidDatePickerRenderer: DatePickerRenderer
  {

    public AndroidDatePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(Control !=null){
           Control.TextSize = 10; //change the size
        }
    }
  }
}
```

For ios:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker), typeof(IosDatePickerRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace
{
  class IosDatePickerRenderer: DatePickerRenderer
  {

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        
        if(Control != null)
        {
            Control.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(10); //change the size
            
        }
    }
  }
}
```